# Different coloured dog tags when knifing

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

When I kill someone with a combat knife in Bad Company 2, the player's name along a dog tag appears on the screen. I have noticed that the colour of the dog tag is not consistent. Sometimes it is a bronze colour and sometimes it's silver. What do these different colours mean and do they have any significance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its based on the persons level.

Bronze: Knife kill a player with the ranking 1-21 
Silver: Knife kill a player with the ranking 22-45 
Gold: Knife kill a player with the ranking 46-50

Source: http://loot-ninja.com/2010/03/25/battlefield-bad-company-2-dog-tags-explained/